# Correct way to securely store Azure blob storage access key in C# app

Tags: c#, azure, security, azure-blob-storage

I am building a c# app (WPF) which uploads log files to an azure blob storage. I store the `StorageConnectionString` inside the `App.config` file like this:

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="StorageConnectionString" value="DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=<my account name>;AccountKey=<my account key>;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net" />
</appSettings>
```

In my code I retrieve the `StorageConnectionString` like this:

```
string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("StorageConnectionString");
```

Everything works fine so far, but I am worried about the **clearly visible** `StorageConnectionString` inside the `App.config` file.

**How can I secure my app that its not possible with reverse engineering to get the `StorageConnectionString`?**

Comment: What kind of app are we talking about and where does it run? How about not using an access key at all but using a [managed identity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/authorize-managed-identity#use-a-managed-identity-to-create-a-block-blob-in-net) so you do not need to store a secret? See also [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/managed-identities-azure-resources/overview)

Comment: @PeterBons I updated my question. It is an WPF app, and it uploads log files to the blob storage.

Comment: If it will run on many PCs, preventing discovery of all its secrets is essentially impossible, and for someone skilled almost trivial.  As Peter says, one option is to require the user to authenticate (e.g. to AAD) and you're then using _their_ credentials to connect.  If that's not feasible, and your log data is not particularly sensitive, you could place an API in between and send the log data to it.  Someone could discover it and send bogus data to it; whether that's okay you'll have to decide.  You could also log to AppInsights instead (with the same security concerns).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your application should **not** be using Shared Keys.  Storage account keys grant full access to your storage account.  A better approach is to use Shared Access Signatures in your application with Azure AD.

A full overview can be found here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-sas-overview

While Microsoft recommends using Azure AD with SAS to authorize requests to Azure Storage. If you must use Shared Key authorization, then secure your account keys with **Azure Key Vault**. You can retrieve the keys from the key vault at runtime, instead of saving them with your application. For more information about **Azure Key Vault**, see [Azure Key Vault overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/general/overview).

All our security recommendations can be found here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/security-recommendations

Answer (score 0):

To securely store your Storage Account access key in C# application, you can use either of the below options:

1. Store the Storage Account Key as an environment variable
2. Use Azure AD Authentication for your blob storage instead of access key